# How do you return an UInt that implicitly narrows and widens in C#?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

In C# you have operators that will implicitly narrow and widen the resulting variable depending on the size of the result.

```
 UInt32 exampleA = 10000000/2;      // Will return a UInt32 
 UInt32 exampleB = 1000000000000/2; // Will implicitly widen to UInt64 and cause a compile error
 UInt64 exampleC = 1000000000000/2; // Will implicitly widen to UInt64 without error
```

Can you do you do this for a method and if so how? I believe it is related to Generic Covariance & Contra-variance but am not sure about how to go about implementing it for a function like below

```
// Will compile but won't automatically widen
UInt32 validVariable= exampleFunction(1,1);
UInt32 invalidVariable = exampleFunction(UInt32.MaxValue,1);

private static UInt32 exampleFunction(UInt32 x, UInt32 y)
{
     return (x+y); //
}
```

---

```
// Won't compile but will automatically widen
UInt32 validVariable= exampleFunction(1,1); // Will cause compile error
UInt32 invalidVariable = exampleFunction(UInt32.MaxValue,1); // Will cause compile error

private static UInt64 exampleFunction(UInt32 x, UInt32 y)
{
     return (x+y); //
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean about widening. The constant is defined as `1000000000000` which is a `long`. You're storing the result of its division into `UInt64` which is (usually?) `ulong`. Both are 64-bit. In the case of `long a = 1`, a compiler directive is emitted: `conv.i8` which converts the value (an int) to a 64-bit value. Also note the division is resolved by the compiler and it's simply emitting constants.

Comment: All of your examples pretty much compile or not compile as you describe. What exactly are you asking? Do you want to create your own type like `UInt32`?

Comment: @Kobi I was trying to figure out how create a function that automatically returned the smallest UInt type based on the return value in the function.

As shown in the answer I have made a bad assumption about how the the operators exhibit this behavior which I was basing my logic around and all I really needed was an overload to replicate the behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics or variance. It's not that the operators themselves widen or narrow. It is that the compiler is permitted to insert implicit conversions for both inputs and outputs. Both of your compiler errors are caused by the fact that there is no built-in conversion from `ulong` to `uint`. There is an implicit conversion from `uint` to `ulong` that the compiler will insert if required. The observed behavior of the division operator is because there are two overloads available for the compiler to choose from. The equivalent thing for you to do would be to define two overloads with the signatures:

```
uint exampleFunction(uint x, uint y)
ulong exampleFunction(ulong x, ulong y)
```

Then if one of the arguments happens to be the wider `ulong` type the compiler will choose the second overload because it is permitted to insert a conversion from `uint` to `ulong`.